# How to switch form one navigation controller to another

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

My **A** view has a `UIImagePockerController` modal controller presented in it's `viewWillLoad` method. After the picture is taken, it is dismissed via:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

After getting to my **A** view, I am switching to my **B** view via:

```
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

The problem is that after switching `tabBarController` (as mentioned above), if the user hits the first tab, the camera is still being shown.

What I understand is that the navigation controller pushes views on its stack until I get to the **A** view where I leave by simply switching tabBar, so it makes sense that the **A** view is still shown when I go back to that tabBar.

How do I reset that navigation stack to its root and **then** switch to tabBar at index 1?

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: In my opinion something is not totally correct the way you are thinking about the navigation. If you are in a specific navigation is not correct to swap to another one as a further step of some sort of action.

Comment: You're probably right, I'm just beginning to learn how to. Could you explain a bit more? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just think in the user perspective, is like you are making him jump from one road to another, what if he/she wants to come back. You can display A in a nav controller loaded modally  and push B when you need. When it's done just dismiss the modal

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

or this :

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

popViewControlleranimated: sets it 1 "step" back in the stack.
popToRootViewControllerAnimated: sets it to the root.